# Only load 10 markers from database

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a question. I make a project using google maps. i put 30 data on database. but when i wanna show the marker on the map, it only load for 10 data. also when I filter my data based on the category, it load for 10 data only. I check inspact element on my browser (im using mozilla) and found this error : "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal" what does it means?

Here's my code to show markers & map on the web :

```html
<?php
$title = "Peta Masjid";
include_once "header.php";
?>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12"> 
          <div class="panel panel-info panel-dashboard centered">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h2 class="panel-title"><strong>  <?php echo $title ?>  </strong></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:380px;"></div>

    
     


 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyAbXF62gVyhJOVkRiTHcVp_BkjPYDQfH5w">
</script>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    
    var mapOptions = {   
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-6.966667, 110.416664), 
        disableDefaultUI: true
    };

    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

    setMarkers(map, officeLocations);

}

var officeLocations = [
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://localhost:8082/sig/getdata.php');
                $no=1;
                if(json_decode($data,true)){
                  $obj = json_decode($data);
                  foreach($obj->results as $item){
?>
['<?php echo $item->id_masjid ?>','<?php echo $item->nama_masjid ?>','<?php echo $item->alamat ?>', '<?php echo $item->longitude ?>', '<?php echo $item->latitude ?>','<?php echo $item->gambar ?>'],
<?php 
}
} 
?>    
];

function setMarkers(map, locations)
{
    var globalPin = 'img/tanda.png';

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
       
        var office = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(office[4], office[3]);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString});
         
        var contentString = 
   '<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<h5 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+ office[1] + '</h5>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+ 
   '<p>' + office[2] + '</p>' + 
   '<p><img src="img/'+office[5]+'" style="width:50%;height:190px;" /></p>' +
   '<p><a href=detail.php?id='+office[0]+'>Info Detail</p></a>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: office[1],
            icon:'img/tanda.png'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', getInfoCallback(map, contentString));
    }
}

function getInfoCallback(map, content) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content});
    return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(content); 
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        };
}

initialize();
</script>



            </div>
          </div></div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php include_once "footer.php"; ?>
```

And here's code to get data from database (getdata.php)

```html
<?php
include "connection.php";
$Q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mosques WHERE category = 'Mushola'")or die(mysql_error());
if($Q){
 $posts = array();
      if(mysql_num_rows($Q))
      {
             while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($Q)){
                     $posts[] = $post;
             }
      }  
      $data = json_encode(array('results'=>$posts));
      echo $data;                     
}

?>
```

Comment: If you're writing new code, **_please_ don't use the `mysql_*` functions**. They are old and broken, were deprecated in PHP 5.5 (which is so old it no longer even receives security updates), and completely removed in PHP 7. Use [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with _prepared statements_ and _parameter binding_ instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/354577 for details.

Comment: Might be helpful: [SyntaxError: unterminated string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unterminated_string_literal)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a counter in your while loop that counts to ten and then breaks the loop or an if statement than only runs if the counter is not 10

-Aron DC